# TypeError: int object is not callable

Tags: python

I am using python, and I have been facing this error for a week.

```py
<module>
    my_car.odometer_reading ()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

What is the solution please?

```
 class Car:
    def __init__(self,made,module,year):
       self.made=made 
       self.module=module
       self.year=year
       self.odometer_reading=0


   def update_odometer(self,mileage):
      self.odometer_reading = mileage

 my_car=Car('audio','q5','2021')

 my_car.update_odometer(23)
 my_car.odometer_reading ()
```

I tried a lot but without any result.

Comment: ```my_car.odometer_reading``` remove the parenthesis. ```()``` is used to call a function. Adding ```()``` in front of ```my_car.odometer_reading``` tell python that it is a function. But in the class, it is an integer. So it raises an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`odometer_reading` is not a function, its an `int`, so just print it

```
print(my_car.odometer_reading)
```